# Coffeescript / JQuery not detecting form submit click in rails update action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, stripe-payments

I have a profile form which updates user information.In this form there are fields to enter Credit Card Information. Stripe is being used as the payment gateway.
I have followed Ryan Bates episode on [integration of rails with Stripe](http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe?autoplay=true).

The only difference(what I see is) between his example and my implementation is that he uses a new form where as my form updates.

This is my form partial written in haml:

```
= form_for([@user, @profile], url: user_profile_path(@user), :html => { :multipart => true }) do |f|

  - unless @profile.avatar.url == '/avatars/original/missing.png'
    = image_tag @profile.avatar.url(:square)
  = f.file_field :avatar, hide_label: true
  %h3 Credit Card Information
  - if @profile.stripe_customer_token.present?
    Credit card has been provided.
  - else
    = f.hidden_field :stripe_customer_token
    = f.text_field :credit_card_number, :autocomplete => false, label: "Credit Card Number", id: "card_number"
    = f.text_field :card_code, :size => 4, :autocomplete => "off", label: "CVV Code", id: "card_code"
    .field
      = label_tag :exp_month, "Card Expiration"
      %br
      Month
      = select_month nil, {add_month_numbers: true}, {name: :exp_month, id: "card_month", class: "form-control"}
      %br
      Year
      = select_year nil, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year+15}, {name: :exp_year, id: "card_year", class: "form-control"}
    #stripe_error
      %noscript JavaScript is not enabled and is required for this form. First enable it in your web browser settings.
  %br
  = f.submit nil, id: "update_profile"
```

and this the coffee script:

```
jQuery ->
  Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
  profile.setupForm()

profile =
  setupForm: ->
    $('#update_profile').submit ->     ##### LINE A #####
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', true)
      if $('#card_number').length
        profile.processCard()
        false
      else
        true

  processCard: ->
    card =
      number: $('#card_number').val()
      cvc: $('#card_code').val()
      expMonth: $('#card_month').val()
      expYear: $('#card_year').val()
    Stripe.createToken(card, profile.handleStripeResponse)

  handleStripeResponse: (status, response) ->
    if status == 200
      $('#profile_stripe_customer_token').val(response.id)
      $('#update_profile')[0].submit()      ###### LINE B #####
    else
      $('#stripe_error').text(response.error.message)
      $('input[type=submit]').attr('disabled', false)
```

**The Problem**

1. On clicking submit on the browser, coffee script does not detect the form submission at LINE A.
2. Introducing a random link and changing LINE A to find that link- from submit to click, detects the user click but LINE B does not work.

**Question**

Why does the coffee script not detect the user click and how do I get this to work.

Can this be done with Java script?

Comment: Does `setupForm` get called? Is there an `id="update_profile"` in the DOM when it does? Is `#update_profile` a `<form>`? Why would expect a submit to work when you still have a `#card_number` element? Wouldn't it make more sense to check for the presence of `$('#profile_stripe_customer_token').val()`?

Comment: `setupFor` does get called. There is an `id="update_profile"` in the DOM at that time. Not sure how to check if `#update_form` is a `<form>` (How do I validate that)? `$('#profile_stripe_customer_token').val()` could be done as well, i was just copy pasting Ryan Bates code.

Comment: A quick look in a DOM inspector will tell you what `#update_profile` is. Or you could look at `$('#update_profile')` in the console. I don't see how copy'n'pasting code is in your best interests, if you don't understand the code then you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: BTW, the `= f.submit nil, id: "update_profile"` in your HAML would suggest that `#update_profile` is an `<input type="submit">`, not a `<form>`. You need to bind your submit handler to the `<form>`.

Comment: `#update_profile` is an `<input type="submit">`. How do I "bind" the submit handler? this is how to the DOM element looks - `<input id="update_profile" class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Update Profile" name="commit">`. Rails did not assign an id, so I manually assigned one. I am sensing from your reply that it is bad/incorrect practice

Comment: Manually assigning an `id` is fine. You could also use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the `<form>` that wraps your submit button: `$('#update_profile').closest('form').submit -> ...`

Comment: Even after using closest, it still did not detect the click.

Comment: Does `$('#update_profile').closest('form')` find anything? You need to try a bit harder to debug your code, that's why you need to understand the code you're writing rather than copying and pasting a bunch of incomprehensible magic.

Comment: Using firebug and the console, `$('#update_profile').closest('form')` does return the form. But the coffee script does not detect the submit. To debug I have placed javascripts alerts all over to know how much of the coffee script has run .

Comment: Great it works now! But it does not work when the user navigates to that page. It only works when the page is refreshed. Making me think hat the coffee script does not load each time a new page is loaded.

Comment: Never mind I guess that is another question. I can accept your answer as the solution if you post it.

Comment: The "it does not work when the user navigates to that page" part sounds like a TurboLinks issue.